# Tag Request - PLS

Tags: discussion, tags

I was going to create a new tag for the site for `pls` (Partial Least Squares), but this action requires 1500 reputation. A quick search of this subject on the site returns multiple pages of relevant questions. I thought it would be helpful to be able to index these questions accordingly.

Could someone who has higher reputation create this tag? I would be happy to sort through the relevant questions adding the new tag once created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is the tag: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partial-least-squares